# How to soft-cancel a Paypal subscription?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Suppose a user signs up for a yearly subscription today, and cancels tomorrow: clearly, I want him to be able to user my app for the full year, because he paid for the full billing cycle. And I want to know that, because I want to be able to tell him: "Your subscription was successfully canceled but you may use this app until next May 14 2024".

In Stripe, rather than canceling a subscription right away, you can change its `cancel_at_period_end` from false to true; the subscription remains `active` until the end of the billing cycle, and only then it is changed to `canceled`. When the user cancels, I can use the `customer.subscription.updated` webhook to verify that `cancel_at_period_end` has become 'true' and change the user's status to `will_cancel` or something.

How can I do this with Paypal? Perhaps a workaround could be that, when the user cancels the subscription, I don't actually cancel it but just suspend it, and change the user's subscription in my db to `will_cancel`; then, I will let a cron job check when the subscription's next payment is due, and if this date is older than today, I can definitively cancel the subscription via API and then change the user's subscription's in my db to `canceled`.

Would there be any drawbacks to this solution? Are there better options?

Comment: If you're using IPN, you don't have to care about the `cancel` event: you will get a `subscr_eot` message at the end of the term, which is the time to end his service.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you describe is neither special nor consequential, and there is nothing you need to do to address it specifically.

For all subscription scenarios, register a listener for the webhook event PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED , and anytime one is received use the event to update your own record's valid-through date in your database. This is all you need to do, for both the initial payment as well as every future payment. Other than payment exceptions like refunds, disputes, or chargebacks (which can be handled manually) there are no other events of any consequence

If it aids in reconciliation, add a `custom_id` parameter in the initial createSubscription. This will be returned in all future webhook events for a subscription.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand how to use PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED: in this case, I would save May 14 2024 as the next payment date, so a cron job on May 15 2024 would cancel the subscription because its next payment date is in the past, ie. it wasn't renewed. But the user's subscription will remain active until May 14 2024, even if he canceled on August 1 2023! From August 1 2023 to May 14 2024, how does my app know that the user canceled, so that I can tell the user: "Your subscription was successfully canceled on August 1 2023 but you may continue to use this app until May 14 2024"?

Comment: It's not necessary. All you need to do is display payment history and the period they're currently subscribed through. A cancellation of future subscription payments doesn't change this.

Comment: So again PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED is the only important webhook, and a fully functional implementation can depend on it -- and it alone. If you really want to show extra messaging when a user cancels future billing, there are additional subscription webhook events: https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions --- however they are not worth spending time on. A feature to reactivate or resubscribe when lapsed is what would be important.

Comment: So, if a user cancels their Paypal sub from their dashboard on Aug 1 2023, and then logs into my app, he sees that his last payment was made on May 14 2023, and that he is subscribed until May 14 2024 ('cause that's the date I still have in my db). How does that confirm him that my app knows his Paypal sub was canceled? It's confusing! Also, what if a client required this? What if the client doesn't want a payment history? Paypal should provide as much data as possible, as soon as possible, and let the developers decide how to use it.

Comment: The bottom line here is that I want subs in my db to be always synced with the underlying Paypal sub. What if I want to know how many active subs I have at the moment for internal statistics? How can I rely on the statuses in my db if some active subs are actually canceled? A cron job will eventually tell me that they're canceled but I want to know right away! And I agree that the other BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.* are useless since they do not fire when a subscription is canceled via the dashboard...

Comment: "I want subs in my db to be always synced with the underlying Paypal sub" -- the key is to realize they are not the same thing. A PayPal sub's future billing being cancelled does not mean any access needs to change, since it needs to continue as active in your system same as before, until and unless it received a new payment.  Only a subscription lapsing without a new PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED within the expected time+grace period means something must change on your end.  Other events do fire when a subscription is "cancelled" they just are not important. Focus on what is important.

Comment: For me everything is important, I like to sweat the details. Anyway, I have discovered BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CANCELLED does fire when a subscription is canceled from the dashboard, so problem solved.